# Issue with ejabberd status after making changes in ejabberd.yml file

Tags: ejabberd

I installed ejabberd using

**root@arun-pc:/home/arun# apt-get install ejabberd**

Here is my /etc/hosts file

```
**127.0.0.1  localhost**
**172.30.13.130 arun-pc.pratian.com**
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And here is my configuration of **ejabbered.yml under listening port** section

```
listen:
-
port: 6222
ip: "::"
module: ejabberd_c2s
##
## If TLS is compiled in and you installed a SSL
## certificate, specify the full path to the
## file and uncomment these lines:
##
certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
starttls: true
##
## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
##
## starttls_required: true
##
## Custom OpenSSL options
##
protocol_options:
       - "no_sslv3"
##   - "no_tlsv1"
max_stanza_size: 65536
shaper: c2s_shaper
access: c2s
zlib: true
resend_on_timeout: if_offline
 -
    port: 6269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
```

Later I registered admin using this command

```
1. **ejabberdctl register admin arun-pc.pratian.com password**
User admin@arun-pc.pratian.com successfully registered
```

2. Later I added this in **ejabberd.yml for ACL rights for admin**

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
     - "admin@arun-pc.pratian.com"
```

After these changes I restart ejabberd using command **ejabberdctl start**
It successfully restarted and when i checked the status using command

```
**root@arun-pc:/home/arun#ejabberd status**      



here is the image of the issuse that i am facing

[Issue after changes][1]     


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFXaw.png
```